# Deserialize Xml to different type

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

This question may be that I am not asking the question correctly but the conflicting names and classes make it difficult. I'm wanting to build up a small tool which tracks my code metrics as I refactor some code. The results now output to a file which I am trying to deserialize. Here is a snippit of the metrics. (Sorry that is as small as I could make it)

```
<CodeMetricsReport Version="11">
<Targets>
    <Target Name="C:\Git\coab\GoldBox.Logging\bin\Debug\GoldBox.Logging.dll">
    <Modules>
        <Module Name="GoldBox.Logging.dll" AssemblyVersion="1.0.5978.28510">
        <Metrics>
            <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="88" />
            <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="30" />
            <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="13" />
            <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="1" />
            <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="51" />
        </Metrics>
        <Namespaces>
            <Namespace Name="GoldBox.Logging">
            <Metrics>
                <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="88" />
                <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="30" />
                <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="13" />
                <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="1" />
                <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="51" />
            </Metrics>
            <Types>
                <Type Name="Config">
                <Metrics>
                    <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="89" />
                    <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="9" />
                    <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="5" />
                    <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="1" />
                    <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="15" />
                </Metrics>
                <Members>
                    <Member Name="BasePath.get() : string" File="C:\Git\coab\GoldBox.Logging\Config.cs" Line="8">
                    <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="98" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="0" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                    </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="BasePath.set(string) : void" File="C:\Git\coab\GoldBox.Logging\Config.cs" Line="8">
                    <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="95" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="0" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                    </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="LogPath.get() : string" File="C:\Git\coab\GoldBox.Logging\Config.cs" Line="9">
                    <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="98" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="0" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                    </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="LogPath.set(string) : void" File="C:\Git\coab\GoldBox.Logging\Config.cs" Line="9">
                    <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="95" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="0" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                    </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="SavePath.get() : string" File="C:\Git\coab\GoldBox.Logging\Config.cs" Line="10">
                    <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="98" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="0" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                    </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="SavePath.set(string) : void" File="C:\Git\coab\GoldBox.Logging\Config.cs" Line="10">
                    <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="95" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="0" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                    </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="Setup() : void" File="C:\Git\coab\GoldBox.Logging\Config.cs" Line="13">
                    <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="67" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="3" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="7" />
                    </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="CreateIfNeeded(string) : void" File="C:\Git\coab\GoldBox.Logging\Config.cs" Line="25">
                    <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="84" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="2" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="2" />
                    </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                </Members>
                </Type>
            </Types>
            </Namespace>
        </Namespaces>
        </Module>
    </Modules>
    </Target>
</Targets>
</CodeMetricsReport>
```

I was working my way down with

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = XElement.Load(@"C:\Git\coab\MetricResults\immer@DESKTOP-2KSR2T6 2016-05-15 05_27_14.mrx");
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Target));
    xml.Dump();
    xml.Descendants("Target")
        .Select(e=>(Target)serializer.Deserialize(e.CreateReader()))
        .Dump();
}
public class Target 
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Module> Modules {get;set;}
}
public class Module
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AssemblyVersion {get;set;}

    public List<Metric> Metrics {get;set;}
    public List<Namespace> Namespaces {get;set;}
}
public class Namespace
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Metric> Metrics {get;set;}
    public List<Type> Types {get;set;}
}

public class Type
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Metric> Metrics {get;set;}

}
public class Metric
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

When I got to `Type` I knew that I could depend on LinqPad putting my `Type` in its own unique namespace and the code would work. However for the code I want to write I don't want it to be `Type`, I'd rather it be `MetricType` however when I change the `Type` to `MetricType` in the class `Namespace` I get back zero results. So the question is how can I make `Namespace` look like this instead?

```
public class Namespace
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Metric> Metrics {get;set;}
    public List<MetricType> Types {get;set;}
}
public class MetricType
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Metric> Metrics {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialiser will infer element and attribute names from the type and property names.  If you want different names, you have to add attributes to explicitly define the names you want to use.

The attribute you want here is `XmlArrayItem`, which specifies the name for the items within the list:

```
public class Namespace
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Metric> Metrics { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("Type")]
    public List<MetricType> Types { get; set; }
}
```

Just to give you more of a flavour, if you wanted to be explicit about all names in this class, you'd need these attributes:

```
[XmlRoot("Namespace")
public class Namespace
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Metrics")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Metric")]
    public List<Metric> Metrics { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Types")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Type")]
    public List<MetricType> Types { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7jNAhN) for a working demo.

Comment: I looked through a bunch of the Xml___Attribute and didn't see that `XmlArray` or `XmlArrayItem` Thank you very much. I ended up cheating and using LINQ and Select to get around this, but I might just give this a try for closure purposes